# How can i disable ALT+ mouse from moving the window in windows 10?

Tags: windows, windows-10

In windows 10 pro when i hold alt then left click and drag it moves whichever window im clicking on.  The problem is, i use ALT+click-drag in certain programs and it keeps moving the window around.

Very annoying.

Is there a way to disable it?

Comment: Are you saying that if you drag and drop a window it moves the window?  Because ALT+LEFT CLICK isn't a Windows 10 keyboard shortcut, it isn't anything, I don't understand what shortcut your asking about.

Comment: interesting, that would mean something else is causing it. If i hold alt, left click any window, and start dragging it moves the window around.

Comment: Being able to left click a Windows Explorer window and move it around the display has been around since Windows 3.1.  Are you talking about how you can shrink the actual display on a monitor in Windows 8.1+ ( alt + left click isn't a shortcut to that behavior ) though.  [Here is a near complete list of shortcuts added in Windows 10](http://www.howtogeek.com/198122/32-new-keyboard-shortcuts-in-the-windows-10-technical-preview/)

Comment: as mentioned, this should not exist on its own. I suspect you have 3rd party app causing this (like AltDrag), are you the only one using the computer? make sure you recognize all programs listed under control panel > programs and features. and try to remember when this started.

Comment: Hah, the ALT+click-drag shortcut is something I'm familiar with in Linux desktops (e.g. Gnome) but not in Windows, not even the latest Windows 10.  It's quite possible your mouse driver software is implementing the feature.  I'd investigate that.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry all! bit stupid on my part.  Spent a while looking at this last night and it turns out an auto hotkey script i use for work (and home) got updated by a colleague.  The update added a script to move windows around holding alt.  All fixed now.  Interestingly, I didn't even know AHK could do so much.